# How a byte is stored in an integer

Tags: java, inputstream

In InputStream class of the java.io.* package :

int read() throws IOException

read() returns a byte as it is under the bytestream class, but it is stored in integer ,without any error.

Why is it so ?? and how is it happening. Help me the memory allocation design also

Comment: technically the "byte" is unsigned, whereas Java's `byte` is signed. So while its is a "byte" as in 8-bits, it is not a `byte` as in Java's primitive type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can up-cast freely (from a primitive that uses *less* bytes to one that uses *more* bytes), because you loose no information (you can put a small thing in a large container).

It is only when you down-cast (from a primitive that uses *more* bytes to one that uses *less* bytes) that you must explicitly cast (when you put a large thing in a small container, you risk chopping some of the thing off to make it fit)

Answer (score 4):

The context is given by the javadoc, which says:

> *"Reads the next byte of data from the input stream. The value byte is returned as an int in the range 0 to 255. If no byte is available because the end of the stream has been reached, the value -1 is returned."*

Under the hood, the `read` method either has a byte to return or the stream is at the EOF position.  The return value can therefore 257 possible states, and (obviously) that won't fit into a `byte`.  The API deals with this by returning an `int`, encoded as specified by the javadoc excerpt I've quoted above.

I haven't looked at the code, but I expect it is something vaguely like this:

```
    if (eof) {
        return -1;
    } else {
        // Casting to an int sign extends to 32 bits,
        // and we then take the bottom 8 bits.
        return ((int) someByte) & 0xff;
    }
```

And when you get the result you need to do something like this:

```
    int res = is.read();
    if (res == -1) {
        // handle EOF case ...
    } else {
        byte b = (byte) res;
        // handle the byte ...
    }
```

---

> Help me the memory allocation design also.

There are no memory allocation issues.  The `byte` and `int` types are primitive types.

Answer (score 2):

An `int` in Java is 32 bits. A `byte` in Java is 8 bits. Try the following code:

```
byte foo = 5;
int intFoo = foo;
```

Java allows you to upcast primitives for free because you are not losing any information by doing so.